# Does useEffect block rendering the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, use-effect

I would like to do a little load time every time the user arrives or reloads the page. I use for that a useEffect () which has a setTimeout () and which simply sets the variable setLoading to false after 1 second. But my question is does this setTimeout block the return of the function?
Otherwise it is useless since I would like this useEffect to allow the page to load the html and render it almost instantly.

```js
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  });
```

```js
      {isLoading ? 
        <Loading />
      : (
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Header showModal={showModal} />
              <div className="top">
                <div className="leftPart">
                  <Presentation />
                  <Skills />
                </div>
                <Timeline />
              </div>
              <Projects />
              <Footer />
              <ConnexionModal showModal={openModal} hideModal={hideModal} />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/admin">
              <Admin />
            </Route>
            <Route path="*">
              <Erreur404 />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      )}
```

Comment: No, it will not block the execution of code. According to the code execution plan of JS (Event Loop), the execution will push the setTimer() callback to callback queue and continue executing other things, once the timer is expired it will pickup the setTimer() callback and executes it (only if no other task is in execution). To understand the event loop check this video by **Akshay Sahani:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8zKuNo4ay8E&t=969s

Comment: The `useEffect` return function is a cleanup function and will only run when the component unmounts. Say for instance the component mounts then unmounts in less than a second, you need the cleanup to clear the timeout otherwise this update state on an unmounted component (which in turn causes an error).

Comment: check `useLayoutEffect`

Comment: Thank you for your answers. So this is not the right way to do a loading screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's non-blocking by definition.

But, if you want to implement a loading logic, `useEffect` is definitely the right tool.

You just need to pass a second argument to it.

```js
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
```